# jquery or alike code generator

Tags: user-interface, mockups

I'm looking for code generator that will help me to create mockup for web based GUI.  I need to support tabs, buttons lists etc .. I don't care which technology used. 
Something similar to MFC/QT  or any another GUI libraries usually provided as part of IDE. 
I'm don't have any knowledge in java scripts/HTML and want something very simple that i can use for GUI prototyping.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to get "fancy" with you GUI (in which case it's doubtful there's a rapid prototyper for it) it will look very similar to anything you'd build with native widget toolkits. MFC and QT *already* support tabs, buttons and lists.

Barring that, Dreamweaver or heck even Frontpage can probably do what you want. It would be advisable to gain some knowledge of HTML and JS *before* starting your endeavor; unless of course you're paying a programmer who does ;)

Comment: I specifically needed web interface and mfc/qt is not an option. Any way i passed it over to our web master and he did the job :)